# does .htacces on Apache manage access via ftp or only via http?

Tags: linux, apache

I'm new in this situation. I would like to protect my website (hosting linux) and i found this method (.htacces editing). But i would like to know if an error on .htacces can deny to me the access on my website via ftp. Is .htpacces only about http access?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apache is a *web server*, it's doesn't handle *ftp* requests, so configuration files don't have any effect on that service.

Answer (score 0):

No it can not since your web server (most likely Apache) is not taking care of FTP.